# .NET 4.8 is missing

Tags: .net, windows-10

I have a problem with .NET 4.8. When I try to install a program that requires it, it claims that the .NET 4.8 is missing. It seems to me that there is a certain difference in the versions of .NET, my operating system seems to be installed. When I look at the versions installed on the command line, I get this:

> C:\Users\ANV>dir /b %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*
>   v1.0.3705
>   v1.1.4322
>   v2.0.50727
>   v3.0
>   v3.5
>   v4.0.30319

So it looks like I only have .NET 4.0. However, looking in the Windows registry, under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`
I have 4.8.03752 as version. Since I am using Win 10, I cannot uninstall .NET completely, I tried the repair tools from Microsoft's website, but they did not help. In addition, the installer for .NET claims that I have .NET 4.8 already installed. Ideas?

Comment: All .NET FW 4.x versions share the same runtime

Comment: .NET 4.8 installs into the `v4.0.30319` directory - it's an in-place upgrade of 4.0

Comment: Are you sure the program refusing to install is asking for 4.8 framework and not, say, the 4.8 SDK?

Comment: this is exactly message I am getting when I run installer ".NET Framework 4.8 is not present on the computer."

Comment: Is the application one you built or did you get it from a vendor?

Comment: It is a package from someone else. I am actually not very well acquinted with .NET, but it seems, that the package was build with .NET 4.8 528049 release version. As far as I undestand, this is release used with windows versions other than Win 10 versions 1905 and 1909. Those use .NET release 528040. Since my PC is actually running on 1909, I have 528040 .NET release. I tried to install given program on Win 7 virtual machine which has 4.8 528049 version and it runs correctly there, so it seems to me that incorrect .NET release version was indeed issue.